# Have I reach the limit of objects in a array?

Tags: javascript, php

I gather around 6000 user ID in a javascript array. I post them into a php file and print it out. Then I only get 999 objects.

Have I reached a limit?

Javascript

```
var emails_massa = '';
$('.checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    emails_massa += 'valda_kunder_checkbox_email[]=' + 'id=' + $(this).val() + '&';
});

$.post(
    'mail_visa_kunder_fran_massa.php', 
    emails_massa,
    function (data) {
       $(".send_email_adress").html(data)
    });
```

PHP

```
$kund_array = array();
$kund_array = $_POST['valda_kunder_checkbox_email'];
print_r($kund_array);
```

Comment: I doubt it very much. The problem is probably with the way you're posting them to PHP. Please show your code.

Comment: Yes if it is actually a "POST" then its just based on your server configuration(php.ini) for example: php_value post_max_size = 10M

Comment: I have now added my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the number 999 is suspiciously round I guess you're hitting [`max_input_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars).

If on a public site, I wouldn't recommend blindly raising this limit, for security reasons, instead, consider some serialization on the client side (e.g. join the ID's with Javascript, send them as one single input field and split into an array in php):

```
JS:

var emails_massa = [];
$('.checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    emails_massa.push($(this).val());
});

$.post(
    'mail_visa_kunder_fran_massa.php',
    'valda_kunder_checkbox_email=' + emails_massa.join(),
    function (data) {
        $(".send_email_adress").html(data)
    });
}

PHP:

$kund_array = explode(',', $_POST['valda_kunder_checkbox_email']);
print_r($kund_array);
```

Comment: If you look at the code you can see that the data is sent as a single big string. So there is only 1 input var

Comment: @Joren: by default, jquery interprets the `data` param as a query string.

Comment: Tried it on my localhost and it worked!! thg435, you are an angel. Thank you! <3

Answer (score 2):

You've reached the max post size of your PHP. You can increase it in two ways:

**php.ini**

```
post_max_size=20M
upload_max_filesize=20M
```

**.htaccess**

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
```

Which one to use depends on what you have access to.

Comment: I tried with the .htaccess with no success. Could I go around it with using get instead of post?

Will contact my server provider aswell regarding this.

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, 999 IDs still isn't a lot of data, maybe 100 kB in extreme cases. If it did hit the post_max_size limit, $_POST should be empty according to the docs, not just contain the first X bytes of data.